# Why can't I display a string on a TextArea from a frame to frame another with processing multiple Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm learnning to process multiple thread in java with simple socket example.

**Server Form**

```
package chat_server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;


public class TCPServer extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    ArrayList clientOutputStreams;
    ArrayList<String> users;
//    ArrayList<Object> lstUsers;

    public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {

        BufferedReader reader;
        Socket sock;
        PrintWriter client;

        public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket, PrintWriter user) {
            client = user;
            try {
                sock = clientSocket;
                InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
                reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                ta_chat.append("Unexpected error... \n");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String message, connect = "Connect", disconnect = "Disconnect", chat = "Chat";
            String[] data;

            try {
                while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    ta_chat.append("Received : " + message + "\n");
                    data = message.split(":");

                    for (String token : data) {
                        ta_chat.append(token + "\n");
                    }

                    if (data[2].equals(connect)) {

                        sendToChatRoom("connect");

                    } else if (data[2].equals(disconnect)) {

                        sendToChatRoom("disconnect");

                    } else if (data[2].equals(chat)) {

                        sendToChatRoom(message);
                    } else {
                        ta_chat.append("No Conditions were met. \n");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ta_chat.append("Lost a connection. \n");
                ex.printStackTrace();
                clientOutputStreams.remove(client);
            }
        }
    }


    public TCPServer() {
        initComponents();
    }

         // initComponents()

    private void btn_startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        new ChatRoom().setVisible(true);
        Thread starter = new Thread(new ServerStart());
        starter.start();

        ta_chat.append("Server started...\n");
    }                                         

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TCPServer().setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    public class ServerStart implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList();
            users = new ArrayList();

            try {
                ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(2222);

                while (true) {
                    Socket clientSock = serverSock.accept();
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSock.getOutputStream());
                    clientOutputStreams.add(writer);

                    Thread listener = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSock, writer));
                    listener.start();
                    ta_chat.append("Got a connection. \n");
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ta_chat.append("Error making a connection. \n");
            }
        }
    }

    public void sendToChatRoom(String message) {
        Thread chatroom = new Thread(new ChatRoom(message));
        chatroom.start();
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btn_chatroom;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn_clear;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn_end;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn_start;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn_users;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea ta_chat;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**ChatRoom Form**

```
package chat_server;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ChatRoom extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable {

    ArrayList<String> users;
    String message;

    /**
     * Creates new form ChatRoom
     */
    public ChatRoom() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public ChatRoom(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            if (this.message != null) {
                System.out.println(this.message);  // run
                ta_chatroom.append(message); // can't run
            }
             ta_chatroom.append("null");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void initComponents() {
             // GUI
       }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ChatRoom().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> lst_users;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea ta_chatroom;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

My program includes serveral threads such as create socket thread , send/receive buffer thread , create chatroom form thread run with open form another the same time.

My idea is when I start server by press button start, this event will also open chatroom form. I want to Client's buffer write to server then it also be displayed on chatroom's textarea.

My problem : When a client sends request to server and chat room thread also sends buffer to chatroom form to display on textarea then my program throws a exception. Although message isn't null ( I checked with `System.out.println(message)` at run method on chatroom class and this message displayed on console), `ta_chatroom` variable of JTextArea throws a `NullPointerException.`

I don't know how to solve this problem. Can you help fix it and explain why? Perhaps, My way confuse to solve this solution so you can suggest me solve way.

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   chat_server.ChatRoom.run(ChatRoom.java:44)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: You must try to split your big problem into smaller ones. Looking for a "nullpointerexception" cause in all this code is tiresome.

Comment: Where is `ta_chatroom` initialized ?

Comment: @J.Chomel: I reduced code, just show things that I think have relate to my problem.

@Berger: I think that `ta_chatroom`'s JTextArea auto initialized in initComponents. Is this right?

Comment: `public class TCPServer extends javax.swing.JFrame` == Baaad Idea.

Comment: @Fildor: What do u mean? I'm a newbie in java

Comment: You are mixing too many responsibilities into one single class. Write a "Network-stuff" class or even some of them and use those in your GUI-Classes. You may want to read something about "MVC" pattern.

Comment: What happens in case of your string-parameterized constructor? You do not call `initComponents` there ...

Comment: @Fildor: Follow OOP architecture. Default constructor will be called before constructor another implement. So default constuctor called  `initComponents `  then constructor another will be inheritanced.

Comment: Erm, no. If you call `new ChatRoom( "Somestring" );` the paramless CTOR will not be called automagically. Step it through in debugger.

Comment: @Fildor: haha, sorry I stupied . LOL, feeling empty